# Adding glowing to TextView in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm currently working on a project where I'm supposed to use text with a glowing background , something like this
[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `android:shadowColor`, `android:shadowDx`,`android:shadowDy` & `android:shadowRadius` in TextView defination inside xml. Check this discussion [How to make text glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692804/how-to-make-text-glow)