# Inner Glow in Android

Tags: android, layout, glow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make text glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692804/how-to-make-text-glow)

I am wondering how to add an inner glow to a TextView in my Android layout.

I have searched and only was able to find how to do Inner Shadow on Android.

Is there a convenient and fast way to get inner glow to surround a TextView please, or get a similar effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `android:shadowColor`, `android:shadowDx`,`android:shadowDy` & `android:shadowRadius` in TextView

Comment: Will try that! Thanks a lot! :) I will let you know if I get it to work.

Comment: I am having some issues seeing the inner glow. I am also including an android:background which has a <shape> with a solid color and corners. I have tried removing the android:background, and changing the inner glow from #FFFFFF to #000000 but I still do not see it. Any clue please?

Comment: I think I did not explain my question correctly. I wanted to make inner glow for the TextView itself (the boundaries of my rectangle), and not the text (there is actually no text in it). I believe I need to use 9-patch.