# How to make a glow effect on the text in TextClock android

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, clock

Can anyone help me make the **glow effect** in `TextClock` i have tried the method stated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692804/how-to-make-text-glow)! but it has no effect can anyone help please.

This is what i am doing using back support library of `textClock` and want glow in it

```
        <cz.vhrdina.textclockbackport.TextClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:shadowColor="@color/red"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="8"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Post some code and we'll look at it.

Comment: posted the code please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using this code, make sure you test it on Device because the emulator or graphical viewer doesn't support this.

```
          <cz.vhrdina.textclockbackport.TextClock
            android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:shadowColor="@color/shadow_color"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
```