# How to make text glowing like neon in android

Tags: java, android, xml

> Hi i am facing a problem in android textview as i want it to
> glow(shining) like Neon font i have no idea how to get textview glow or shiny i am not getting any solution code,

```
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adText"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ad"
                android:clipToOutline="true"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

in activity class as text is set from editext in a layout and sent via bundle in nextactivity here i need to display it as shining (gloweffect) i tried with different sources from github but not working   https://github.com/cchandurkar/Glowy

> adText.setText(bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("text"));

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make text glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692804/how-to-make-text-glow)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily download the fonts which you need and you can easily use them, you can easily download fonts using [this](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Neonderthaw) site.

Here are the steps to use fonts in your android textview

1. download the fonts which you required
2. copy those fonts in the `res -> font` folder. (remember you need to create a font package inside the resource folder and add a fonts there)
3. at last `android:fontFamily` property in your textview, which looks like this `android:fontFamily="@font/neons"`

and it's done!

Comment: yea but , the text should be like glowing neon fonts..i have already saved fonts in assets folder https://i0.wp.com/css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/neon-light-2.png?w=434&ssl=1